# Form action with class and method adds to existing url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have sign in form which has URL - "http://localhost/ci/signin". After click on submit, it goes to - "http://localhost/ci/login/userLogin", which affects hyperlink opening problem because it searches for that page in 'login', which is actually on "http://localhost/ci/home".

How to solve this problem?

my signin form page code is:

```
 <?php echo form_open('login/userLogin'); ?
        <div class="top-margin">
        <label>Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
         <?= form_input(['name'=>'email','class'=>'form-control']); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="top-margin">
        <label>Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
         <?= form_password(['name'=>'password','class'=>'form-control']); ?>    
        </div>
       <hr>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <b><a href="">Forgot password?</a></b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
            <?= form_submit(['name'=>'submit','value'=>'Sign in','class'=>'btn btn-action']); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

My "login" controller code is:

```
    class Login extends MY_Controller
    {
    public function userLogin()
    {
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
     $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</p>");
     if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {
        $data['title'] = ucfirst('signin'); // Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->view('user/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/nav', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/signin', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer', $data);
     }
     else
     {
        echo "Success";
     }
 }
 }
  ?>
```

Routes:

```
 $route['(:any)'] = 'user/view/$1';
 $route['default_controller'] = 'user/view';
 $route['404_override'] = '';
 $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and your code correctly (never used codeigniter), you have the form loading from the login directory.

```
<?php echo form_open('login/userLogin'); ?
```

What happens when you try:

```
<?php echo form_open('home/userLogin'); ?
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use CodeIgnite myself, but it probably has helper functions which can correctly output an URL.

In Laravel it is:

```
url('this/url/is/not/added/to/the/current/url');
```

Even when you're at 'localhost:8000/somepage' this outputs:

```
"localhost:8000/this/url/is/not/added/to/the/current/url"
```

It is a PHP (helper)function, so output it in PHP.

Comment: I didn't get any helper like this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I found solution of my problem. It was my mistake actually. `Hyperlinks` was not working because i didn't write `full address` for that `hyperlinks`.
Previously, My hyperlinks was-

```
<a href="home">Home</a>
```

Now, I changed it to...

```
<a href="<?= base_url();?>home">Home</a>
```

Now, It Works. Enjoy.